# How would I go about changing CPPickerView (a simple UIPickerView replacement) to use a clear background instead of an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview, drawrect

Right now, CPPickerView uses an image for the background, as shown in its drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Draw background
    [self.backgroundImage drawInRect:self.bounds];

    // Draw super/UIScrollView
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // Draw shadow
    [self.shadowImage drawInRect:self.bounds];

    // Draw glass
    if (self.showGlass) {
        [self.glassImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width / 2 - 30, 0.0, 60, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

All I want it for my CPPickerView to have the same color as the view behind it, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I tried the following code in the drawRect to no avail (it just causes a white stripe in the background):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100.0,0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,100.0, 100.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

How would I go about making it clear?

Answer (score 0):

As it says on the [GitHub](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView) page:

To customize the appearance, replace the following images with your own:

- wheelBackground.png
- stretchableGlass.png
- shadowOverlay.png

Answer (score 0):

Creator of CPPickerView here - the problem is the version of CPPickerView you'd have been using had no way of NOT drawing those images. If you simply leave the images out of our project, I believe it will just draw a black box for them as well, which obviously isn't what you want.

To get around this, you could create clear images for `wheelBackground.png` and `shadowOverlay.png` and turn off the glass (`picker.showGlass = NO`).

**However**, I've also just updated CPPickerView to version 1.1.0. This update exposes the `backgroundImage`, `glassImage`, and `shadowImage` as public properties, so after creating your CPPickerView you can simply set them to `nil` and the images won't be drawn at all:

```
CPPickerView *picker = [[CPPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
picker.backgroundImage = nil;
picker.shadowImage = nil;
picker.glassImage = nil;
```

CPPickerView will still look for the named images by default though (for backward-compatiblity), so if you don't want them drawn you explicitly need to set them to `nil`.

Hope this helps!